# How can a 3DBarChart be made to be fixed size and proportions?

Tags: output-formatting, graphics3d

I have a 3DBarChart that adds bar graphs as would be required by the dataset, but as it gets wider runs off the page and can not be printed.  Is there a way to fix the height & width of the 3DBarChart so that it maintains it's size and proportions and will not become too large to print regardless of the dataset it receives?  Thanks!

Comment: Use `ImageSize` to tell Mma what the width of the final output should be. For example: Export["~/Desktop/plot.png",ImageSize->730], will this work for you? Perhaps you did not want to export the graphics, in that case you apply ImageSize-> directly on the BarChart command I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anon suggests, ImageSize is the key. For instance:

```
BarChart3D[Range[5], ImageSize -> 500]
```

fixes the size at 500, no matter how many data points it has. You can find this kind of thing out for yourself using the built in help. When you look at the help file for `BarChart3D`, found by the shortcut `?BarChart3D`, you can read "BarChart3D has the same options as Graphics3D", so anything that you can do with 3D graphics in general, you can do with BarChart3D in particular.